# Automating Baseline Profile Generation in Android with non-release builds

Tags: gradle, baseline-profile

I'm working on an Android app and utilizing baseline profiles with the new Gradle plugin and GMD, as outlined in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/baselineprofiles/configure-baselineprofiles#support-gmd). My app requires the BaselineProfileGenerator class to run on a pre-populated database with mock data, which I manage using a demo build type in my Gradle configuration:

```kotlin
buildTypes {
    getByName("release") {
        isMinifyEnabled = true
        // ... other configurations ...
    }
    register("demo") {
        initWith(getByName("release"))
        matchingFallbacks.add("release")
        // ... other configurations ...
    }
}
```

Using the `generateDemoBaselineProfile` Gradle task, I can generate the `baseline-prof.txt` file in `app/src/demo/generated/baselineProfiles/`. However, I currently have to manually copy this file to `app/src/main/baselineProfiles/` so that the release build can make use of it.

**The Problem:** I want to automate this process using `automaticGenerationDuringBuild = true`, but I'm facing challenges. Ideally, I'd like to use the `mergeIntoMain = true` setting:

```kotlin
baselineProfile {
    saveInSrc = true
    mergeIntoMain = true
    automaticGenerationDuringBuild = true
}
```

With this, I can run `generateBaselineProfile` and everything should get merged into one baseline profile in `app/src/main/generated/baselineProfiles/`. The problem with this is that non-demo baselineProfile generation tasks like `generateReleaseBaselineProfile` are triggered as well and fail quickly because `BaselineProfileGenerator` can't do its job without the prepopulated data provided only in that `demo` build type. The solution would be to somehow disable these other gradle tasks and make sure only `generateDemoBaselineProfile` gets triggered when I run `generateBaselineProfile`.

Perhaps an even more elegant way of solving this would be to `generateDemoBaselineProfile` on `automaticGenerationDuringBuild = true` and force it to copy `baseline-prof.txt` to `app/src/main/generated/baselineProfiles/`.

I have no idea how to do either of these things. Any help would be greatly appreciated.